# How to only retrieve records that don't match a value in another table in Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I'm trying to create a query that will return a result from a table if it doesn't match a value in a joined table.

I've tried the following:

```
    $unknownrenewals = $dm->createQuery('
    SELECT mcp.hqProcessed AS payProcessed, mcp.paymentType, mcp.refundAmount, mcp.refunded, mcp.memberNo, mcp.firstName, mcp.surname, mcp.giftaid, mcp.created, mc.id AS mcid, mc.firstName AS mcfirstName, mc.surname AS mcsurname
    FROM InstructorBundle:MapCentrePayments mcp
    LEFT JOIN InstructorBundle:MapCentreContacts mc WHERE mc.id = mcp.memberNo
    WHERE mc.id != mcp.memberNo
    AND mcp.paymentResult = :result
    AND mcp.paymentType = :type
    AND mcp.hqProcessed = :processed
    ORDER BY mcp.created DESC'
    )->setParameters(array(
                'result' => '1',
                'type' => '1',
                'processed' => '0'
    ))
    ->setMaxResults(150);

    $unknownren = $unknownrenewals->getResult();
```

But this doesn't retrieve any records at all. If I remove the `mc.id != mcp.memberNo`, then all the records are displayed, even the ones that don't match the `mc.id` value to `mcp.memberNo` value. I don't want to pass the responsibility to the Twig view (where I know I could hide the correct values), so I'd like to solve this problem within the controller.

Comment: WHERE mc.somename IS NULL

Comment: There will always be a value in `mc.id` and `mcp.memberNo`, but the values won't always match up to their respective tables. Using NULL in the condition won't fix that.

Comment: What is this? It isn't `DQL` that is certain. As far as I read the docs you cannot join entities just like that plus you have `WHERE` clause twice...

Comment: "WHERE mc.id = mcp.memberNo WHERE mc.id != mcp.memberNo", what are you writing? absolutely there's no records.

Comment: You can join entities like what I have done, but where you would use `ON` in the query, you can only use `WHERE`. Try it out with your own project, the `WHERE` clause in the join doesn't affect the second `WHERE` clause.